# What would be the opposite to hasFields?

Tags: coffeescript, rethinkdb

I'm using logical deletes by adding a field `deletedAt`. If I want to get only the deleted documents it would be something like `r.table('clients').hasFields('deletedAt')`. My method has a `withDeletes` parameter which determines if deleted documents are excluded or not.

Finally, people at the #rethinkdb IRC channel suggested me to use the `filter` method and that did the trick:

```
query = adapter.table(table).filter(filters)
if withDeleted
    query = adapter.filter (doc) ->
        return doc.hasFields 'deletedAt'
else
    query = adapter.filter (doc) ->
        return doc.hasFields('deletedAt').not()
query.run connection, (err, results) ->
...
```

My question is why do I have to use `filter` and not something like:

```
query = adapter.table(table).filter(filters)
query = if withDeleted then query.hasFields 'deletedAt' else query.hasFields('deletedAt').not()
...
```

or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [hasFields](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/has_fields/) function can be called on both objects and sequences, but [not](http://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/not/) cannot.

This query:

```
query.hasFields('deletedAt')
```

Behaves the same as this one (on sequences of objects):

```
query.filter((doc) -> return doc.hasFields('deletedAt'))
```

However, this query:

```
query.hasFields('deletedAt').not()
```

Behaves like this:

```
query.filter((doc) -> return doc.hasFields('deletedAt')).not()
```

But that doesn't make sense. you want the `not` to be inside the `filter`, not after it. Like this:

```
query.filter((doc) -> return doc.hasFields('deletedAt').not())
```

Comment: Thanks @atnnn, that's exactly what I did. Just was wondering if there wasn't a lets say more fluent way to express that exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

One nice that about RethinkDB is that because of the way queries are built up in host language it's very easy to define new fluent syntax by just defining functions in your language. For example if you wanted to have a lacksFields function you could define it in Python (sorry I don't really know coffeescript) like so:

```
def lacks_fields(stream, *args):
    res = stream
    for arg in args:
        res = res.filter(lambda x: ~x.has_fields(arg))
    return res
```

Then you can use a nice fluent syntax like:

```
lacks_fields(stream, "foo", "bar", "buzz")
```